# Is it worth to use Selenium com.thoughtworks.selenium.Wait class for waiting? (Performance)

Tags: java, selenium, wait

Selenium has class [com.thoughtworks.selenium.Wait](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.testatoo.openqa/selenium-java-client-driver/1.0.2_20090715/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Wait.java) for convinience. I use it in next way:

```
public void waitForElement(final String locator){
    Wait a = new Wait(){
        @Override public boolean until(){
             selenium.isElementPresent(locator);
        }
    }

    a.wait("Cannot found locator " + locator, TIMEOUT);
}
```

As I understand each time when I call my function new anonymous class will be created and then created object of this class. Or only one anonymous class will be created?

Anyway. How faster is just using `Thread.sleep()` directly inside `waitForElement` method then creating new object each time? How big can be this difference?

Comment: @djangofan My question was half a year early!!!

Comment: @djangofan And, don't you see they are completely different questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be precise, the anonymous class is only created once (during compilaton) and only loaded once.

It will be *instantiated* each time you call the method, but that overhead is pretty small.

If you do this a lot, then you can easily create a (non-anonymous) class:

```
public class ElementPresenceWait extends Wait {
    private final String locator;

    public ElementPresenceWait(final String locator) {
        this.locator=locator;
    }

    @Override public boolean until(){
        selenium.isElementPresent(locator);
    }

    public void wait(long timeoutInMilliseconds) {
        wait("Cannot found locator " + locator, timeoutInMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

Then you can do the simpler

```
new ElementPresenceWait("foo").wait(1000);
```

Comment: thanks. this is the way to do.  
I can even create setter for locator property so I even should not create new instance everytime, just changing locator property

Comment: @nahab: you *could*, but I wouldn't do that. The overhead of creating the object is very, very small (especially when your program is prepared to wait 1000 milliseconds anyway) and having an immutable object simply makes a huge selection of problems impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I dare say the difference is minimal and you should use what makes the code more readable. In my personal opinion, using the Wait class is more readable.

Comment: I agree.  Using the standard Wait, WebDriverWait, or parent class FluentWait is what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the internal implementation of  com.thoughtworks.selenium.Wait, however generally I prefer to write "smart waits" which checks first, then sleeps for a quarter of a second, then checks again, then sleeps and so on until a max timeout is reached.

This allows for faster execution when waiting for something than a thread.Sleep which must always wait the maximum sleep time.

Comment: These "smart waits" are great, and normally work, but I find that there are a handful of cases where scripts have a tendency to 'outrun' the browser, (not giving time for javascript to load for example) and there's no good way to detect the transition.

Comment: hmmm. Internet Explorer exposes the readystate property to tell when it is loading or not, and that combined with javascript injection if required for AJAX has worked for me. In fact I can't recall when it hasn't. (But that does not mean that it has always worked 100%)